# Decode large string base64

Tags: php, base64, decode

I have to decode a large string base64 encoded:

```
<?php
        $str ='base64code';
    echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

The link contains the base64 encoded string: http://www.interwebmedia.nl/dataxi/base64.txt

Online decoders give the right result but this php function doesn't. Is there a solution?

Comment: 92K isn't overly large. Chances are you pasted it in incorrectly rather.

Comment: I tried it several times, but it gives some correct information, but unstructured and incomplete. For example: the base64 decryption with the php-script above starts with 2014-03-08T12:23:

Comment: Works fine here: https://eval.in/116212

Comment: I tried it several times, but it gives some correct information, but unstructured and incomplete. For example: the base64 decryption with the php-script above starts with 2014-03-08T12:23:                                         and the decryption with a decrypter on the internet starts with: <Gebeurtenis xmlns="http://www.gebeurtenis.org">      which is the correct data.

Comment: @ Amal Murali, thats the correct data, could it be that there is an old version of php running on the server?

Comment: `base64 -d base64.txt > plain.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`base64_decode`](http://php.net/base64_decode) outputs exactly what was encoded before. It does not adapt any contained values.

You are writing everything out in HTML context. And there any `<tags>` will not be shown in the browser window. Use show source. Or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: That really helped a lot, thanks. Do you also know a way to let php structure the data>?